# Как устранить проблему с запуском Oracle XE?

Tags: sql, oracle

На комп установлена Oracle XE. Листенер точно работает. Через SQL Plus подключение проходит. Но как только пытаюсь открыть в браузере ссылку по Get Started, чтобы перейти на сайт, то вылетает ошибка:

> Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Вычитала, что проблемы могут быть из-за порта 8080, который может быть занят. В cmd с помощью netstat просмотрела список портов. 0.8080 вообще не используется.

Comment: на какой сайт вы пытаетесь зайти? Enterprise Manager? а XE его поддерживает?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите зайти на сайт Enterprise Manager, то сперва посмотрите его порт. Сделать это можно с помощью такого запроса:

```
SQL> select dbms_xdb.getHttpPort() from dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       8080

SQL> select dbms_xdb_config.getHttpsPort() from dual;

GETHTTPSPORT
------------
        5500
```

Потом заходите на localhost:port